# Expectation of Geometric Random Variable Simulation

Tags: distributions, simulation

I have the following code for simulating a geometric random variable where $X \sim \text{Geometric}(p)$, $0 \leq p \leq 1$, and pmf is $p(n) = (1 - p)^np$:

> 1. Set $X = 0$.
> 2. Generate $U \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$.
> 3. If $U \leq (1-p)$ set $X = (X + 1)$ and return to (2).
> 4. Else return $X$,

Obviously this is an inefficient approach to say generating one with, $\lfloor \text{ln}(U) / \text{ln}(1 - p)\rfloor$, since a small $p$ rarely goes through multiple iterations.

**My question:** With a simulation in R, I can calculate an estimated number of times we will loop through for a $p$. But I would like to have an actual equation to which I can calculate the expected number for any arbitrary $p$ to compare with more efficient algorithms.

How do I go about calculating this? Obviously, $E(U)=.5$, do we need to condition this on $1−p$?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Apologies, updated.

Comment: The number you're generating is geometric. The number of times you add 1  to the count before you stop and output your geometric value is therefore ... geometric, so your question is just "What's the mean of a geometric(p)?" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution (see the sidebar on the left near the top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are just simulating [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) that starts from $0$.

When we simulate $U ~\sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ and compare the value with $1-p$, it is equivalent to tossing a coin with probability of tail being $1-p$ where we view probability of obtaining a head as the success event. Note that we have $Pr(U \leq 1-p) = 1-p$.

The corresponding mean is $\frac{1-p}{p}$.

Edit:

The expected number of rounds that is required is $\frac{1-p}{p}+1=\frac1p$